# Import scribe-1.2.1.jar in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, scribe

What are the steps to import scribe-1.2.1.jar in android studio?

I have added the jar in the lib folder and have also added it using the add library option. But when I compile I am facing compile time error.

Gradle: package org.scribe.builder does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Edit your module's `build.gradle` file, just append one line in the `dependencies` scope.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/scribe-1.2.1.jar')
}
```

FYI: at this time Android Studio project setting did not affect the gradle build, so you must edit it yourself.

there are a [user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) for gradle android plugin.